# Music Stopped notification

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, mpmovieplayercontroller

Am using MediaPlayer framework to play the video in my iPhone application. I am using the Notifications available in the Mediaplayer framework. But whenever my audio/music stops, I am not getting any notifications.

So I wonder in iOS , is there any other framework can be used to get notified when the music alone stopped. Can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this observer:

```
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackState:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:self.ctl];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification object:self.ctl];
```

Selectors would be:

```
- (void)moviePlayBackState:(NSNotification*)notification {
  //called when music stopped or paused
}

- (void)moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {
  //called when music finished
}
```

Comment: No. I have used those notifications too. Actually, some times in my MPMoviePlayer the video stalls. When the video is stalling , I am not getting any one of the notifications provided by MPMoviePlayer. So I thought I can give a try for Music stop notification.